# Entity framework update object and change reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to make update on CustomerRailcard object which has a reference on Railcard object with end * to 1. The problem is, that I cannot delete Railcard object, I have to only change reference on CustomerRailcard object to another RailcardObject. 
I'm doing it like this:

UPDATE:

```
// Updating properties in existing CustomerRailcard. 
// This won't update navigation properties (Railcard).
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(existingCustomerRailcard, EntityState.Modified);
context.ApplyCurrentValues("CustomerRailcardsDbo", newCustomerRailcard);

// Now I'm trying to update navigation property of CustomerRailcard to the Railcard
// by removing the reference from old Railcard to CustomerRailcard. 
// Railcard can have references to many CustomerRailcards.
var oldRailcard = railcardRepository.FindById(customerDetails.CustomerRailcards.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == railcard.Id).Railcard.Id);
var customerRailcardToRemove = oldRailcard.CustomerRailcards.FirstOrDefault(cr => cr.Id == railcard.Id);

// Removing reference to CustomerRailcard from Railcard
oldRailcard.CustomerRailcards.Remove(customerRailcardToRemove);


// Now I'm getting new Railcard I want to have referenced by CustomerRailcard
// and I'm changing its reference tu CustomerRailcard
var newRailcard = railcardRepository.FindById(railcard.Railcard.Id);

// Adding reference to CustomerRailcard
newRailcardDboReference.CustomerRailcards.Add(railcard);
```

After running this I'll get this error

A relationship from the 'CR_RL_FK' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'CustomerRailcardDbo' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

How else should I perform update on this kind of relationship?

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to remove `customerReilcardToRemove` from the navigation property - than only breaks relation but does not delete the `CustomerReilcard` instance. Your relationship requires that `CustomerReilcard` has a principal `Reilcard` so you must either delete `customerReilcardToRemove` instance by calling `DeleteObject` or make the relation nullable and keep orphan instances.

Comment: But DeleteObject will physically delete object from database. I need somehow only to change reference to another Railcard.

Comment: Your code is so complicated that I'm not able to understand what are you trying to do. Simply if you remove dependent entity from from principal navigation property you must add the same entity to other principal or you will get exception. Your code is imho only removing the entity from navigation property but not inserting it to another one.

Comment: I've updated code and its comments. I hope it's clearer now. Basically what I have is one table called Railcards with railcard names and other things, which is immutable. I can't delete or change anything there. Then I have second table called CustomerRailcard, where each Customer Railcard has reference to railcard from Railcards table. When I perform update, I'm trying to change only reference in Customer railcard from one railcard to another. I will appreciate any help.